# how to escape a quote in javascript without jslint crying foul

Tags: javascript, maven-3, jslint, yui-compressor

how would I escape the quote in the following line of code so that jslint doesn't throw a warning on it. Currently it throws an "Unclosed string" warning on this line.

```
    input = input.replace(/""/g,"\\\"");
```

I am using the maven yuicompressor plugin for minifying the js & css and also checking the js files with jslint. Here's my configuration for the plugin.

```
    .....
    <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
                <goal>jslint</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>                   
            <excludes>                  
              <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
              <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
    .......
```

Comment: What you have should be fine. This passes at http://jslint.com: `"\"\"".replace(/""/g, "\\\"");`

Comment: It doesn't throw any error in the online tool

Comment: Working with the jslint vim plugin. What editor/jslint plugin are you using?

Comment: Here's the error that I get [INFO] check file :C:\Users\workspace\src\main\webapp\js\app.js
[WARNING] ...\src\main\webapp\js\app.js:line 51:column 39:Unclosed string.

        input = input.replace(/""/g, "\\\"");

Comment: Can you give us more of your file?  What happens if you move from `"` to `'`?  So if you try `'spam "" spam'.replace(/""/g,'\\"');` ?  Is the error **only after** minification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is technically an answer but I was using version 1.3.0 when I got this error. Upgrading to version 1.3.4 fixed the problem and no longer shows the jslint error on that line.